# WSO2 EI-6.1.1 with IBM MQ8 integration issue while posting message to target queue

Tags: wso2, ibm-mq

```
TID: [-1] [] [2017-08-09 12:07:00,546]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  [MessageContext: logID=4cc6574b7acd53b2510b0e78661a4db2bff0d346d5081397] null {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-08-09 12:07:00,546] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.AsyncCallback} -   {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.AsyncCallback}
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendOverJMS(JMSSender.java:224)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:200)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1] [] [2017-08-09 12:07:00,546]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.AsyncCallback} -  Executing fault handler due to exception encountered {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.AsyncCallback}
```

followed this link "http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.in/2015/03/configuring-ibm-mq-with-wso2-esb.html"

Note: able to receive messages from queue but not able to send to queue, giving Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Can you check the jar files that you have included from IBM are all the same version.  I would suggest you download and include only those jar files in the IBM MQ v8 Java redistributable client, this should be just `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` and `jms.jar`.  You can check the versions of your current jar files with the command `unzip -p filename.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version`  It is possible the error you are receiving is caused by a missing jar file or mis-matched versions.

Comment: @JoshMc, tried above command its same version(8.0.0.3) which i am using

Comment: The NullPointerException isn't coming from IBM code, it's coming from Apache's axis2. Assuming this is a part of WS02, perhaps upgrading that will resolve things?

Comment: Decompiling your version of JMSSender could shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

added following propertys before send mediator it started wortking

```
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
            <property name="JMS_IBM_PutApplType" scope="transport" type="INTEGER" value="2"/>
            <property name="JMS_IBM_Encoding" scope="transport" type="INTEGER" value="785"/>
            <property name="JMS_IBM_Character_Set" scope="transport" type="INTEGER" value="37"/>
            <property name="JMS_IBM_MsgType" scope="transport" type="INTEGER" value="8"/>
            <property action="remove" name="Accept-Encoding" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="Content-Length" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="User-Agent" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="JMS_REDELIVERED" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="JMS_DESTINATION" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="JMS_TYPE" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="JMS_REPLY_TO" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="Content-Type" scope="transport"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="gov:endpoint"/>
            </send>
```

Comment: one more question , is that all properties mandatory to send messages to IBM MQ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of the transport headers. Adding the following property before the endpoint would suffice:

```
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. Can you elaborate why we need to remove the TRANSPORT_HEADERS in this instance?

Comment: It is because what you are trying to send is a jms message and not an http message. Transport headers are for http messages.

Comment: I see. Do you know why don't I need to do this when transforming a message from FIX to MQ also?